# Adding ActionListener to JComboBox without items not working

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Below is the source code for `UseTest.java`. Why doesn't it work?

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;

class Test implements ActionListener{
 JFrame f ;
 JPanel p ;
 JComboBox cb ;
 JLabel l ;

 Test(){
  f = new JFrame("Test") ;
  f.setSize(200, 200) ;

  p = new JPanel() ;
  p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1)) ;

  cb = new JComboBox() ;

  cb.addActionListener(this) ;

  for(int i = 1 ; i <= 20 ; i++)
   cb.addItem(i + "") ;

  //cb.addActionListener(this) ; //doesn't throws exception here


  l = new JLabel() ;
  l.setForeground(Color.red) ;

  p.add(l) ;
  p.add(cb) ;

  f.add(p) ;

  f.setVisible(true) ;
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

  if(cb.getSelectedItem() != null){
   display() ;
  }
 }

 private void display(){
  String str = "" ;
  str = "Combo selection changed to : " + cb.getSelectedItem() ; 
  l.setText(str) ;
  System.out.println(str);
 }
}

public class UseTest{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Test t = new Test() ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything works fine, the listener is correctly added to the JComboBox.

The thing is when you call addItem to the comboBox, the contentsChanged event is fired and your test#actionPerformed method is called which tries to do

```
l.setText(str);
```

But l is a JLabel that is initialized AFTER the cb.addItem loop. So when the event handler is called l is still null, thus the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Running your code, I get a NullPointerException in relation to your JLabel. This has not been initialised by the time the ActionListener is first called upon - when you add your first item is added and selection is therefore changed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good [`ComboBoxDemo`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java) in [*How to Use Combo Boxes*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding an ItemListener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing ActionListener as you do is not a common pattern.

You should better code something like:

```
cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

  if((JComboBox)ae.getSource()).getSelectedItem() != null){
   //Do your stuff
  }
 }
});
```